# Adjective clause introduced by a relative pronoun "which" VS Preposition "including"

Tags: prepositions, relative-pronouns, adjectival-phrases

> By now, the extradition bill that had sparked the protests had been withdrawn, but the movement had come up with a list of demands, ***which included amnesty for arrested protesters, an independent inquiry into police brutality, and universal suffrage***.

Source -: https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2019/12/16/hong-kongs-protest-movement-and-the-fight-for-the-citys-soul

What's the difference between using the relative pronoun "***which***" -- as used in the aforementioned sentence-- and using the preposition "***including***" to provide the list of things?

> By now, the extradition bill that had sparked the protests had been withdrawn, but the movement had come up with a list of demands, ***including amnesty for arrested protesters, an independent inquiry into police brutality, and universal suffrage***.

Is there a specific rule whereby one or the other would be wrong?

Can "Including" be interpreted as providing a non-exhaustive list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=list%20of%20demands%20including%2Clist%20of%20demands%20which%20included&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) showing that both versions are in common use...

[image]

It's entirely a matter of opinion, but *my* opinion is that the continuous form...

> 1: *a list of demands, **including** [list]*

...(which has become significantly more popular over recent decades) is now effectively the default choice for contexts where *[list]* contains every "significant" element. Effectively, ***including*** is often a slight "hedge" (in case the writer forgot something). Personally, I feel the alternative format...

> 2: *a list of demands, **which included** [list]*

...is more likely when it's a ["rule of three"](https://www.presentationmagazine.com/rule-of-three-836.htm) list. In which context ***which included*** effectively means ***for example***, with no significant implication that the list is "complete".

On reflection, it may not be *entirely* a matter of opinion. A logical implication of my position is that ***which include*** should be followed by a list of exactly ***three*** elements, compared to ***including*** (which I contend works better for different numbers of elements).

Obviously it wont apply in every case, but the "rule of three" is such a well-established rhetorical device that statistically speaking it's less likely that ***three*** cited examples would be definitive / exhaustive than lists of different lengths. So in principle I could compare relative frequencies of different list lengths for the two phrasings. And I believe ***which include*** is indeed followed by exactly three items more often than ***including***, in contexts where either phrasing is possible.

---

TL;DR: Literally (and by default) ***including*** and ***which include*** both imply "non-exhaustive" lists, but I think there's a stronger implication with ***including*** that all *significant* elements have been listed, whereas ***which include*** more often just implies ***for example***.

Comment: Putting a TLDR at the end of the answer defeats the purpose.

Comment: I don't see how you justify that. Obviously for such an obscure detail of usage, it's unlikely I could find an "authoritative source" to back up my position in so many words. So I had to write my own "rationale" for my TLDR position - specifically ***including*** a suggestion for further corroborating research. (That someone *else* might like to pursue, since I feel I've done my bit! :)

Comment: TLDR is supposed to be read first. If it's adequate for the reader's purposes, they don't need to read all the details that follow. If you put it at the end, they've already read the details. The appropriate term at that time would be "In summary".

Comment: ...perhaps I should refer to *...my TLDR position - **which specifically includes*** (a *mere selection* of its finer points! :) But seriously - you stick to your style, and I'll stick to mine. Okay?